# How to deserialize raw JSON objects with Moshi/Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

I have a Sticker class and its wrapper:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class StickerDto(
        @Json (name = "totalAnimatedStickers") val total: Int,
        @Json(name = "pages") val pages: Int,
        @Json(name = "data") val stickers: List<Sticker>

)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class Sticker(
        @Json(name = "name") val name: String,
        @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
        @Json(name = "stickerData") val stickerData: JsonObject,
        var isSelected:Boolean = false
)
```

The stickerData attribute comes from the api with a dynamic json object with unknown attributes

```
"stickerData": {}
```

How do I deserialize an object like that using Moshi?

My current retrofit client:

```
 private fun createNewFriendsClient(authRefreshClient: AuthRefreshClient,
                                       preferencesInteractor: PreferencesInteractor): FriendsApiClient {

        val logger = run {
            val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
                httpLoggingInterceptor.level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
            }
        }

        val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logger).authenticator(RefreshUserAuthenticator(authRefreshClient, preferencesInteractor,
                UnauthorizedNavigator(SDKInternal.appContext, Interactors.preferences))).build()


        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttp)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Interactors.apiEndpoint)
                .build()
                .create(FriendsApiClient::class.java)


    }
```

Gives me an

```
"Unable to create converter for class StickerDto"
Caused by NoJsonAdapter for java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.String>
```

error. What converter do I need to use if not that Moshi one? Trying to pull it down as a string also gives an error as it is expecting and object. I just need that string.

Edit, the Json string is very long but it begins like this:

```
{"tileId":"1264373a-24d8-4c10-ae90-d6e8f671410c","friendId":"2c50f187-039a-4f85-b12b-0c802396a611","name":"David Carey","message":"Joined WeAre8","animatedSticker":{"v":"5.5.7","fr":24,"ip":0,"op":48,"w":1024,"h":1024,"nm":"party_popper","ddd":0,"assets":[{"id":"comp_0","layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":3,"nm":"C | Position","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":45,"ix":10},"p":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":0,"y":1},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0},"t":0,"s":[176,892,0],"to":[-6.667,6.667,0],"ti":[0,0,0]},{"i":{"x":0.833,"y":0.833},"o":{"x":0.333,"y":0},"t":7,"s":[136,932,0],"to":[0,0,0],"ti":[-6.667,6.667,0]},{"t":11,"s":[176,892,0]}],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0,0,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":0,"s":[100,100,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"t":7,"s":[115,75,100]},{"i":{"x":[0,0,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.167,0.167,0.167],"y":[0.167,0.167,0]},"t":11,"s":[95,105,100]},{"t":20,"s":[100,100,100]}],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"ef":[{"ty":5,"nm":"Controller","np":13,"mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller","ix":1,"en":1,"ef":[{"ty":6,"nm":"Icon","mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller-0001","ix":1,"v":0},{"ty":2,"nm":"Color","mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller-0002","ix":2,"v":{"a":0,"k":[0.92549020052,0.0941176489,0.0941176489,1],"ix":2}},{"ty":3,"nm":"Position","mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller-0003","ix":3,"v":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Size","mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller-0004","ix":4,"v":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Orientation","mn":"Pseudo/DUIK controller-0005
```

Comment: I think you can write this `val stickerData: JsonObject` as `val stickerData: Map<String, Any>`

Comment: Still getting the error from the question 

  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.util.HashMap in java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Comment: can you please share a snippet of the son? @andrewedgar

Comment: @andrewedgar pls post a snippet

Comment: I don't understand, if the json has unknown attributes, then how are you gonna use the attributes?!

Comment: The whole string gets used by an animation library. Not sure how the library traverses the string.

Comment: Well for that you only need a simple class for the object that has a single `String` field named `stickerData`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `JsonObject` is a class from the gson package, so if you want to use Moshi you will need to switch to `JSONObject` which is the default class supported by Android.

To do this you will need to write your own JSONObject adapter.

First, write your adapter class:

```
import com.squareup.moshi.FromJson
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonWriter
import com.squareup.moshi.ToJson
import okio.Buffer
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

class JSONObjectAdapter {
    
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): JSONObject? {
        // Here we're expecting the JSON object, it is processed as Map<String, Any> by Moshi
        return (reader.readJsonValue() as? Map<String, Any>)?.let { data ->
            try {
                JSONObject(data)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                // Handle exception
                return null
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: JSONObject?) {
        if (value != null) {
            writer.value(Buffer().writeUtf8(value.toString()))
        } else {
            writer.value(null as String?)
        }             
    }
   
}
```

Adjust your retrofit build to provide custom Moshi object when creating the MoshiConverterFactory:

```
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Moshi.Builder().add(JSONObjectAdapter()).build()))
```

and then you are good to go and use JSONObject

```
@Json(name = "stickerData") val stickerData: JSONObject
```

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

[Built-in Type Adapters](https://github.com/square/moshi#built-in-type-adapters) for *Moshi* include *Arrays, Collections, Lists, Sets, and Maps*. A *JsonObject* type is not provided with *Moshi* itself, but it would be an enhanced `Map<String, Any>` anyhow, so just use the `Map` instead of an object.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class Sticker(
        @Json(name = "name") val name: String,
        @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
        @Json(name = "stickerData") val stickerData: Map<String, Any>,
        var isSelected: Boolean = false
)
```

The values are automatically converted as well. Thus you'll find strings, lists or numbers there.

Answer (score -2):

I made stickerData into a Map and used a GsonConverterFactory instead of Moshi.

Comment: Still this doesn't give the solution to the question. Its a workaround. What if we need to use the Moshi instead of Gson?

Comment: yep I'd go with gson, I had to do something similar for a very simple object `[ time: '2019-10-11...' , time : 123456 ]` and just gave up and went gson. Moshi is very cumbersome for simple objects that need a simple adapter.